# Databricks or AWS Lambda for low throughput event driven architecture

Tags: aws-lambda, databricks

I am looking to setup an event driven architecture to process messages from SQS and load into AWS S3.  The events will be low volume and I was looking at either using Databricks or AWS lambda to process these messages as these are the 2 tools we already have procured.

I wanted to understand which one would be best to use as I'm struggling to differentiate them for this task as the throughput is only up to 1000 messages per day and unlikely to go higher at the moment so both are capable.

I just wanted to see what other people would consider and see as the differentiators between the two of these products so I can  make sure this is future proofed as best I can?

We have used lambda more where I work and it may help to keep it consistent as we have more AWS skills in house but we are looking to build out databricks capability and I do personally find it easier to use.

If it was big data then I would have made the decision easier.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda seems to be a much better choice in this case. Following are some benefits you will get with Lambda as compared to DataBricks.

**Pros**:

1. Free of cost: AWS Lambda is free for 1 Million requests per month and 400,000 GB-seconds of compute time per month, which means your request rate of 1000/day will easily be covered under this. More details [here](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/).
2. Very simple setup: The Lambda function implementation will be very straight-forward. Connect the SQS Queue with your Lambda function using the AWS Console or AWS cli. More details [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-configure-lambda-function-trigger.html). The Lambda function code will just be a couple of lines. It receives the message from SQS queue and writes to S3.
3. Logging and monitoring: You won't need any separate setup to track the performance metrics - How many messages were processed by Lambda, how many were successful, how much time it took. All these metrics are automatically generated by AWS CloudWatch. You also get an in-built retry mechanism, just specify the retry policy and AWS Lambda will take care of the rest.

**Cons**:

1. One drawback of this approach would be that each invocation of Lambda will write to a separate file in S3 because S3 doesn't provide APIs to append to existing files. So you will get 1000 files in S3 per day. Maybe you are fine with this (depends on what you want to do with this data in S3). If not, you will either need a separate job to join all files periodically or do a download of existing file from S3, append to it and upload back, which makes your Lambda a bit more complex.

DataBricks on the other hand, is built for different kind of use cases - Loading large datasets from Amazon S3 and performing analytics, SQL-like queries, builing ML models etc. It won't be suitable for this use case.

Comment: Possible solution for the cons: If messages came in close proximity, consider to use firehose to handle appending object.